# How to move empty colliders?

Tags: unity, 2d, collision-detection

I have 2D background in unity on which I would like to add multiple circle, box colliders.
Assets are not separated. I have drawn assets on background.

How to move circle colliders with mouse or keyboard shortcut on the background?
It's not very pleasant to define x,y position wherever needs to go for every collider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use Custom Editor

Add the following code to the background game object:
**Important**: Must be named `MoveGizmo`

**MoveGizmo**

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveGizmo : MonoBehaviour {

    [CustomEditor(typeof(MoveGizmo))]
    public class ColliderMove : Editor {
        private float moveSize = 0.2f;

        public override void OnInspectorGUI() {
            Collider2D[] cols = ((MoveGizmo)target).GetComponents<Collider2D>();
            moveSize = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Move Size", moveSize);
            foreach (var col in cols) {

                // a header for each collider, stating its current offset (location)
                GUILayout.Label(col.offset.ToString());

                // horizontal group is for placing the buttons on the same row
                GUILayout.BeginHorizontal("", GUIStyle.none);

                // repeat button allows you to hold the mouse on the button
                // to continuously move the collider 
                if (GUILayout.RepeatButton("<")) {
                    col.offset += new Vector2(-moveSize, 0);
                }
                if (GUILayout.RepeatButton(">")) {
                    col.offset += new Vector2(moveSize, 0);
                }
                if (GUILayout.RepeatButton("UP")) {
                    col.offset += new Vector2(0, moveSize);
                }
                if (GUILayout.RepeatButton("DOWN")) {
                    col.offset += new Vector2(0, -moveSize);
                }
                GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Note that I've also added a **Move Size** field so you can control the sensitivity of the move.

Adding this code to a gameobject will add the following buttons for each collider on that object:
[image: Buttons on inspector]

Comment: I created script MoveGizmo and copy-pased your code in it. When I closed Mono, error occured **ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.**

Comment: Maybe when you copied the name from the webpage it got in with some garbage html. Try to type the file name manually.

Comment: Also, check this out:
https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/mono-wont-open-files-illegal-characters-in-path.135426/

Comment: It's a lot of code to add. But possible. Just out of curiosity, why don't you use empty game objects for each collider? It would be much easier to control them using unity's built in tools. And you can easily add menu items and even shortcut keys to add new gameobjects already with a box/circle collider.

Comment: Thnaks. Also, is it possible to place the empty collider on top of the image with the mouse ? For example, when you open sprite editor and select **slice grid by cell size**, you can move the rectangle gizmo with mouse in sprite editor. I was wondering how come this logic  is not possible for colliders.

Comment: Also, can you please mark this answer as accepted (the little 'V' by the answer) or just upvote it if you're still waiting for someone else to give a better answer. :-)

Comment: This is great answer. Thank you! Could you tell me how to add  shortcut keys to add new **empty** already with a box/circle collider.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53942/discussion-between-lilotop-and-dan-monsic).